# Run VBA macro when condition is met

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a spreadsheet to train my numerical skills.

Now, I use VBA macros to generate a new problem once the current one has been correctly solved. To do so, I still have to press a button in the worksheet, which costs time and is annoying.

Is there a way that I can execute a macro when a certain condition is met?

for instance:

```
if A1 = "correct!"
then <run macro>
else <do nothing>
```

Also, let me know if you're interested in the spreadsheet, I'd be happy to share it with you guys.

best,
Pieter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this as code for your Worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Range("A1") = "correct!") Then
        ''# do your stuff here
    End If
End Sub
```

`Worksheet_Change` is called whenever something is changed. As it looks like `A1` is calculated, you can not check for `Target` in that case but check for the value of the cell.

Comment: Will also want to test that the value of Target is "correct!"?

Comment: @PreludeAndFugue: Sure, that's what I meant by `do your stuff` :)

Comment: Prelude: thanks for your suggestion. Haven't tried it yet, but Peter Lang is right: I'd like the code to only be executed when the value in the cell is "correct!". 

The target cell is blank when I do not enter an answer, "correct!" when I enter the correct answer and "wrong!" when the answer is, you guess it, wrong. 

do your stuff should then contain another if.. function? 

Pieter

Comment: <do your stuff> ideally should be another Sub that contains all VBA code needed to reset the sheet and generate another set of problems, maybe even including a MsgBox () asking the user to confirm/cancel

If your <do your stuff> really is a MACRO (Excel4Macro) which I don't believe, then the Run statement would have to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I edited my answer. As `A1` is calculated, checking for `Target` was wrong anyway, since changing any cell could result in a change of `A1`.